# Unable to load HTML templates with Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I've been having some issues loading html templates using the Gin framework through the `r.HTMLRender` setting.

It would seem that the templates are not being found.

I have tried to use the following helpers:

- GinHTMLRender: https://gist.github.com/madhums/4340cbeb36871e227905
- EZ Gin Template: https://github.com/michelloworld/ez-gin-template

Neither of these seem to be working when setting the default path for templates (in my case `app/views`); for the purposes of getting to this to work my html template file structure looks like this:

```
/workspace
|-app
  |-views
    |-layouts
      |-application.html
    |-test.html
```

Here is a sample of the Gin loading code:

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-contrib/location"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/static"
    "github.com/michelloworld/ez-gin-template"
)

//CORSMiddleware ...
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    /** CORS middleware **/
}

func Router() {

    if os.Getenv("ENVIRONMENT") == "production" {
        gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    }

    // Initialize Gin object
    r := gin.Default()

    // Cors Middleware
    r.Use(CORSMiddleware())

    // Rate limiting
    rl, err := helpers.RateLimiterMiddleware()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Rate Limiting Initialization error")
    }
    r.Use(rl)

    // Asset provision
    r.Use(static.ServeRoot("/public","app/assets"))

    // Get URL information
    r.Use(location.Default())

    // Attempt with EZ Template, fails
    // I ge this error: "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" when calling c.HTML(...)
    render := eztemplate.New()
    render.TemplatesDir = "app/views/" // default
    render.Layout = "layouts/application"     // default
    render.Ext = ".html"               // default
    render.Debug = true               // default
    r.HTMLRender = render.Init()


    // Attempt with GinHTMLRender, fails
    // I get this error: https://gist.github.com/madhums/4340cbeb36871e227905#file-gin_html_render-go-L110
    /* 
    htmlRender := GinHTMLRender.New()
    htmlRender.TemplatesDir = "app/views/"
    htmlRender.Debug = gin.IsDebugging()
    htmlRender.Layout = "layouts/application"

    log.Println("Dir:"+htmlRender.TemplatesDir)

    r.HTMLRender = htmlRender.Create()*/

    /** Some Routes **/

    // Start web listener

    r.Run(":8009") // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

The corresponding render call is code is the following:

```
/* c is of type *gin.Context */
c.HTML(200, "test", "")
```

For some reason it seems like the `r.HTMLRender` function is not taking into account the template path; I have attempted doing this:

```
_, err := template.ParseFiles("app/views/test.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Template Error")
} else {
    log.Println("No Template Error")
}
```

This code consistently displays "No Template Error", which leads me to believe that the `HTMLRender` assignment is not considering the `TemplatesDir` set variable.

I've been stuck with this issue for some time, and I am not entirely sure how to get it resolved.

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `LoadHTMLGlob()` or `LoadHTMLFiles()` from [gin-gonic/gin#html-rendering](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#html-rendering)?

Comment: I want to go the helper way to reduce loading each template manually when rendering the page. I've actually found the source of my problem with EZ Gin Template, though I haven't tried again with GinRenderHTML. I'll be posting my findings as an answer to my question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some further research I found the source of my problem with EZ Gin Template.

I'm hoping this helps anyone experiencing the same issue.

After taking a deeper look at the helper code, I realized that the template matching pattern is strict and does not search for files recursively; ie. it expects a specific file structure to find template files:

In the default setting, EZ Gin Template requires the following file structure to work:

```
/workspace
- app
  - views
    - layouts
      - some_layout.html
    - some_dir
      - template_file.html
      - _partial_template.html
    - partials
      - _some_other_partial.html
```

In order to allow for other file patterns, the helper set of functions needs to be modified.

In my case, I forked the helper code locally to allow matching 1st level template files:

```
func (r Render) Init() Render {
    globalPartials := r.getGlobalPartials()

    layout := r.TemplatesDir + r.Layout + r.Ext

    // Match multiple levels of templates
    viewDirs, _ := filepath.Glob(r.TemplatesDir + "**" + string(os.PathSeparator) + "*" + r.Ext)
    // Added the following two lines to match for app/views/some_file.html as well as files on the **/*.html matching pattern
    tmp, _ := filepath.Glob(r.TemplatesDir + "*" + r.Ext)
    viewDirs = append(viewDirs, tmp...)
    // Can be extended by replicating those two lines above and adding search paths within the base template path.

    fullPartialDir := filepath.Join(r.TemplatesDir + r.PartialDir)
    for _, view := range viewDirs {
        templateFileName := filepath.Base(view)
        //skip partials
        if strings.Index(templateFileName, "_") != 0 && strings.Index(view, fullPartialDir) != 0 {
            localPartials := r.findPartials(filepath.Dir(view))

            renderName := r.getRenderName(view)
            if r.Debug {
                log.Printf("[GIN-debug] %-6s %-25s --> %s\n", "LOAD", view, renderName)
            }
            allFiles := []string{layout, view}
            allFiles = append(allFiles, globalPartials...)
            allFiles = append(allFiles, localPartials...)
            r.AddFromFiles(renderName, allFiles...)
        }
    }

    return r
}
```

I have not tried a similar solution with GinHTMLRenderer, but I expect that the issue might likely be related to it in terms of the expected file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the templates into the code. The [jessevdk/go-assets-builder](http://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets-builder) will generate a go file that contains assets within the specified directory. Make sure that the file generated is located where the main package is. Gin also provided this as an example in their [Documentation](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/bind-single-binary-with-template/) [For more Info](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/tree/master/assets-in-binary). It will also include subfolders and its files (i. e. assets) in the binary.

Get The generator tool:

```
go get github.com/jessevdk/go-assets-builder
```

Generate:

```
# go-assets-builder <dir> -o <generated file name>
go-assets-builder app -o assets.go
```

Note that `<generated file name>` can also be like `cmd/client/assets.go` to specify the destination of the file to be generated.

Load Template:

```golang
package main

// ... imports

func main() {
    r := gin.New()

    t, err := loadTemplate()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r.SetHTMLTemplate(t)

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "app/views/layouts/application.html", nil)
    })
    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "app/views/test.html", nil)
    })
    r.Run(":8080")
}

// loadTemplate loads templates embedded by go-assets-builder
func loadTemplate() (*template.Template, error) {
    t := template.New("")
    // Assets is the templates
    for name, file := range Assets.Files {
        if file.IsDir() || !strings.HasSuffix(name, ".html") {
            continue
        }
        h, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        t, err = t.New(name).Parse(string(h))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return t, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.  This walks through the directory and collects the files marked with my template suffix which is .html & then I just include all of those.  I haven't seen this answer anywhere so I thought Id post it.

```
// START UP THE ROUTER
router := gin.Default()

var files []string
filepath.Walk("./views", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".html") {
        files = append(files, path)
    }
    return nil
})

router.LoadHTMLFiles(files...)

// SERVE STATICS
router.Use(static.Serve("/css", static.LocalFile("./css", true)))
router.Use(static.Serve("/js", static.LocalFile("./js", true)))
router.Use(static.Serve("/images", static.LocalFile("./images", true)))

routers.LoadBaseRoutes(router)
routers.LoadBlog(router)

router.Run(":8080")
```

Now they don't have to all be nested at the exact depth like the other suggestions ... the file structure can be uneven